# Issue with require gem, when passing git-repo to gem in Gemfile

Tags: ruby, heroku, github, rubygems, sinatra

I haven't done this in the past, so may be I am missing something here.

I changed the Gem files for 'ruby-git' locally and it worked fine. I forked a gem and made same changes to it, in my Github repo.

While building the Sinatra app to push it to Heroku, I changed the `Gemfile` as follows:

```
gem 'git', :git => "git://github.com/silverSpoon/ruby-git.git"`
```

When I run `bundle install`, I get

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Resolving dependencies...
Using rugged 0.21.0
Using sinatra 1.4.5
Using git 1.2.8 from git://github.com/silverSpoon/ruby-git.git (at master)
Your bundle is complete!
```

- But, when I say `⇒  gem list git`, it doesn't show the gem as installed.
- When I run, `⇒  bundle show git`, it shows the path where the gem repo was installed -
  `/Users/jatinganhotra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@527website/bundler/gems/ruby-git-c7fb35af1a99`
- When I run my app, or run `irb` and do a `2.1.3 :001 > require 'git'`
  it get the following error -
  `LoadError: cannot load such file -- git`

Am I missing something silly here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Gems installed by Bundler through git are not handled the same way as normal gems](https://bundler.io/v2.2/guides/git.html):

> Because Rubygems lacks the ability to handle gems from git, any gems installed from a git repository will not show up in `gem list`. They will, however, be available after running `Bundler.setup`.

In order to use the gem you need to do it through Bundler. Either use `bundle exec` when launching IRB or your app, or use [`Bundler.setup`](http://bundler.io/bundler_setup.html) from within your code.

```
$ bundle exec irb
> require 'git' # should work ok
```

or:

```
$ irb
> require 'bundler/setup'
> require 'git' # should also work
```